# How to monitor the unix socket statistics in OSX per-seconds

Tags: macos, sockets, netstat

I can monitor a net-device in the OSX, like below

```
$ netstat -I eth0 -b 1 1000
            input        (Total)           output
   packets  errs      bytes    packets  errs      bytes colls
         5     0        372          4     0        264     0
         0     0          0          0     0          0     0
         4     0        312          6     0        848     0
        16     0       1936         16     0       1638     0
```

Now I want to do the same thing on a named unix-socket. It can be find by command `netstat -nl`:

```
Address          Type   Recv-Q Send-Q            Inode             Conn             Refs          Nextref Addr
 b98abc798af5851 dgram       0      0  b98abc79a73ee69                0                0                0 /tmp/NetpasHelper.recv.socket
```

But I couldn't find anyway to monitor a unix-socket file like it.

I try the command `netstat -c b98abc798af5851 -b`, but I got nothing.

Is there any software or command, can let me do it?

Thanks.